# How do I present One of three messages to users based on client requirements?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

We have a form on our intranet site that employees must complete yearly.

To complete this form, employee must first enter his/her employee ID.

This ID is checked to see if this employee has completed this form before.

Order of processing:

We have several tables on the database but the three most relevant ones are Employees table, dateDetails table and IncomeSource table.

Employee enters his personal information, and proceeds to complete the rest of the form.

The processing order is that employee information is saved to the employees table, the last inserted ID is retrieved and stored in dateDetails table along with date details.

Similarly, as the rest of the forms are completed, the same last inserted ID is also inserted into those other tables along with details of those tables.

This has worked flawlessly for us.

History:

When an employee enters his/her employee ID into a textbox and his/her mouse leaves the textbox, we need to present the employee with one of three different messages.

1. If the employeeID exists on the Employees table, dateDetails table and IncomeSource table AND the date entered into dateDetails table is the current year, then employee's information (name, email, title, and ID) are pulled and displayed on the form and the employee gets a message that "S/he has already completed the form"
2. If the employeeID exists on the Employees table, dateDetails table and IncomeSource table AND the date entered into dateDetails table is previous year's date, then employee's information (name, email, title, and ID) are pulled and displayed on the form and the employee gets a message, "Please verify your information for acuracy and complete rest of the form."
3. If the employeeID does NOT exist on the Employees table, it means this employee has never completed this form before, then employee's information (name, email, title, and ID) are blank on the form and the employee
   gets a message, "Please enter your personal information and proceed to complete rest of the form."

My problem is that the current code below only checks whether employee's information is on the database or not.

```
Protected Sub txtEmpID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtEmpID.TextChanged
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmpID.Text) Then
        Dim Conn As SqlConnection
        'Read in connection String'
        Conn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString)
        Conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * 
                            from Employees e 
                            inner join dateDetails d on e.employeeID = d.EmployeeID 
                            where EmpID=@empID 
                            and Year(d.enterDate) >= 2015  
                            and Year(d.enterDate)<= 2017", Conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", txtEmpID.Text)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            checkusername.Visible = True
            'imgstatus.ImageUrl = "images/NotAvailable.jpg"'
            lblStatus.Text = "Please verify your information for accuracy. Then complete rest of the form."
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            txteName.Text = dr("employeeName").ToString()
            txttitle.Text = dr("empTitle").ToString()
            txtemail.Text = dr("email").ToString()
            txtEmpID.Text = dr("empID").ToString()
        Else
            dr.Read()
            checkusername.Visible = True
            'imgstatus.ImageUrl = "images/Icon_Available.gif"'
            lblStatus.Text = "Proceed"
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            txteName.Text = dr("employeeName").ToString()
            txttitle.Text = dr("empTitle").ToString()
            txtemail.Text = dr("email").ToString()
            txtEmpID.Text = dr("empID").ToString()
        End If
    Else
        checkusername.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

If it is, employee gets a message that it already exists.

If it is not, employee gets a message to proceed.

This not enough.

How do I modify to satisfy the three requirements enumerated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply ask your database for the name, email, title, ID and the last entered date using `MAX` like this (considering that datedetails can have multiple rows with the same employeeID, if not just get rid of the MAX and the GROUP BY):

```
SELECT name, email, title, EmpID, d.enterDate as enterYear
FROM Employees e 
INNER JOIN dateDetails d on e.employeeID = d.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN IncomeSource i on e.employeeID = i.EmployeeID
WHERE EmpID=@empID
```

And then validate the last date entered with Vb.Net. If nothing is returned, then your employee doesn't exists in all the tables.

If you really want to check all the cases in your query, that would do the trick. You'll juste need to look the booleans

```
SELECT name, email, title, EmpID, 
CASE WHEN YEAR(d.enterDate) = YEAR(getdate()) -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as previousYear, 
CASE WHEN YEAR(d.enterDate) = YEAR(getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as thisYear
FROM Employees e 
INNER JOIN dateDetails d on e.employeeID = d.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN IncomeSource i on e.employeeID = i.EmployeeID
WHERE EmpID=@empID
```

For the VB part :

```
If dr.HasRows Then
    'Employee exists'
    If dr("previousYear").ToString() = "1"
        'employee entered his information last year'
    elseif dr("thisYear").ToString() = "1"
        'employee entered his information this year'
    else
        'not his year, nor the previous year'
Else
    'Employee doesn t exists'
End If
```

Comment: thanks for that code. In our case, there can be only one employeeID for one date in dateDetails table because an employee completes this form once a year. The following year, this current year becomes previous year and the following year becomes current year.

The bigger challenge though is modifying the VB to make three evaluations as opposed to two now.

One, to determine if employee has processed this for this year,or last year, or not at all and spit out the appropriate message to the employee.

Comment: @Kenny i changed the queries and add the Vb part. You'll only need to change the comments for the code you'll like to use in this case!

Comment: thanks very much. Are these lines correct?

`d.dateCreated = DATEPART(year,getdate()) -1 as previousYear, 
d.dateCreated = DATEPART(year,getdate()) as this year`

It says incorrect syntax near = 

It also says incorrect syntax near the inner () as in ` DATEPART(year,getdate()) `

Comment: Also, please allow me to ask a silly question, on this code:

`If dr("previousYear").ToString() = "1"`, where did "1" come from?

Comment: @Kenny i adjust the query, sorry thought this query would return a bit, but you need to explicitly ask it to do so. In TSQL there's no `Boolean`, it's just `Bit` which are 1 for true and 0 for false. With the new answer, you'll see it more easily.

Comment: your logic is very good. It works. Thanks so much.

Only small issue is that the else part, is supposed to show this message:

`lblStatus.Text = "Proceed"` to indicate this employee has never taken the form but that message is not showing.

I will close this and give you full credit for your work and I will try and figure out the issue.

Thanks so much

Comment: @Kenny just to be sure, you put this in the else at the spot where i wrote : 'Employee doesn t exists'? The other else is only if the employee exists but for an unknown reason hasn't taken the form this year or the previous year.

Comment: I did not initially but now I did and none is working anymore.

Could be my fault. I am verifying my code.